# Handling right-to-left/left-to-right override characters in user input

Tags: unicode

I need to embed user input in a string; for example, "<User> sent a message".

The problem comes if the user input includes one of the directionality override characters (U+202D or U+202E). If "<User>" includes an RLO character, the displayed string becomes "‪<User>‮ sent a message‬".

My question is how best to handle this. Are there legitimate uses for RLO and LRO, or is stripping them out a plausible option? Otherwise maybe I can wrap the user input with "Left-to-right embedding" (U+202A) and "Pop Directional Formatting" (U+202C), though doing that right probably requires me to make sure that the user input doesn't contain unbalanced PDF characters.

Comment: `Are there legitimate uses for RLO and LRO`, well yes, for example quoting Hebrew or any other RTL language. You need to decide if that's ever going to happen.

Comment: @BurnsBA: Why do you need RLO to quote RTL text? I can just put עברית script in the middle of some LTR text.

Comment: I'm skeptical that users take the time to figure out how to spell words/phrases/sentences in reverse.

Comment: It's not in reverse. You just switch to the hebrew script and start typing, then switch back. Which is far more natural than embedding exotic unicode control characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there legitimate uses for RLO and LRO, or is stripping them out a plausible option?

I strip them, along with all the other characters designated [not suitable for use in markup](http://www.w3.org/TR/unicode-xml/#Suitable).

Legitimacy is an arguable point, but real Arabic/Hebrew/etc keyboards can't type BiDi control characters, so you are not likely to come across them in non-malicious user input.

Comment: Thanks @bobince. It's looking like stripping them out is the right thing to do.

Comment: It's worth noting that I am explicitly *not* using markup here (if I were, I could wrap the input in a <span unicode-bidi="isolate"/> element, which would solve the problem), so it's not completely obvious to me that the recommendations in that link apply. I'm also still interested in whether there are genuine non-malicious uses for these characters.