# Convert NSCFString to NSString with ""

Tags: objective-c

how convert NSCFString to NSString?

I try to retrieve the phone number with:

```
 NSArray *phoneArray = (__bridge NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(phoneProperty);
if ([phoneArray count] > 0) {
                    if ([phoneArray count] > 1) {

                            phone = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [phoneArray objectAtIndex:0]];

                    }else {
                        phone = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [phoneArray objectAtIndex:0]];
                    }
                }
```

When I try to display the number, I have the special characters that appear "\U0000202a":

Number_phone __NSCFString * @ "\ U0000202a + 33 0 00 00 00 00 \ U0000202c" 0x0000000170a77c40

Comment: `__NSCFString`s are `NSString`s. `U+202a` ([LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202a/index.htm)) and `U+202c` ([POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202c/index.htm)) are Unicode control characters that specify text direction on input; the phone number was likely typed in with these explicitly specified by the keyboard. Is there something this is preventing you from doing, or just unexpected?

Comment: Does that mean I can delete these Unicode control characters? I want to send the number in an http query

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41487035/handling-right-to-left-left-to-right-override-characters-in-user-input. In your case, since you're expecting a string of numbers, it's likely that you can strip those characters without needing to worry about directionality, since they wouldn't affect much.